# Do PyCharm handles local packages differently?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm, python-import

I have a following package structure:

```
project\
  app\
    main.py
    __init__.py
  lib\
    funcs.py
    __init__.py
```

When I try to import my functions from `funcs.py` to `main.py` using `from lib.funcs import func1, func2` it works perfectly fine in PyCharm, but not in VS Code. In VS Code I get:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib'`

However, if I chage the structure to:

```
project\
  main.py
  lib\
    funcs.py
    __init__.py
```

it works fine in VS Code as well.
Why is that? Is there are a way to run imported code from the `app` package like in the first example?
I tried to play around with `__init__.py` files, making and unmacking different folders a packages, using the `from .lib.funcs import func1, func2` and using `from project.lib.funcs import func1, func2`. In the first case I get:

`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package'`

While in the second:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'`

Comment: Go ask in the pycharm forum instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `launch.json` and add

```
    "env":{
        "PYTHONPATH":"${workspaceFolder}"
    }
```

In `main.py`, import modules like `from lib import func`. This solution only works when you **Run without Debugging**:

[image]

**The second way** is adding the following code before importing modules, and you don't need to add args `env` in launch.json

```
import sys
sys.path.append("./")
```

Clicking the green button on the top right corner to **Run Python File in Terminal** and **Run without debugging** both works.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked.
May I ask you: is this how people organise Python code in VS Code? Using `import sys
sys.path.append("./")`?

Comment: `sys.path` is a list and includes file paths that will point to modules you want to import. It's appreciated that you [mark](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) it as accepted for more people with similar questions to reach this solution.